# observer design pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following notification sent for an Observer and Observable design pattern

```
private void changeEnvironment()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        season = SEASON[random.nextInt(3)];
        dayInTime = DAY_IN_TIME[random.nextInt(2)];
        temperature = random.nextInt(120);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(season);
        notifyObservers(dayInTime);
        notifyObservers(temperature);
    }
```

However, in my:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    }
```

How do I check whether it's season, dayInTime, or temperature?

Comment: What are the type of season and dayInTime?

Comment: [This post](http://ayp-sd.blogspot.com/2013/01/observer-design-pattern-in-java.html) could be interesting for you. It describes how to build Observer design pattern implementation using modern Java facilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the observer pattern in pull mode , which means that observable will pass itself to the observer 's `update()` .So , observer can get properties they want from the observable 's getters.

I assume `temperature`, `dayInTime` , `season` in your subject are both `int`

So , you `Observable` (i.e Subject) will looks like :

```
public class Subject extends Observable{

    private int temperature;
    private int dayInTime;
    private int season;

    private void changeEnvironment() {
        Random random = new Random();
        this.season = SEASON[random.nextInt(3)];
        this.dayInTime = DAY_IN_TIME[random.nextInt(2)];
        this.temperature = random.nextInt(120);
        setChanged();

         /** Notify all of the subscribed observers about its changes
          It will call each observers' update(this, null)***/
        notifyObservers();
    }


    public int getTemperature(){....}
    public int getdayInTime(){.....}
    public int getSeason(){....}

}
```

Then your observer can get temperature, dayInTime , season by using the corresponding getters of your Observable :

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

   Subject = (Subject) o;
   int temperature = o.getTemperature();
   int dayInTime= o.getdayInTime();
   int season= o.getSeason();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your code, the `arg` in `update(Observable o, Object arg)` will be one of season, dayInTime or temperature. The argument to `notifyObservers()` is what gets passed to `update()`.

You probably want to include more metadata in a custom 'event' object and use that as an argument for your calls to `notifyObservers()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `notifyObservers("season");` and in the Observer's `update(Observable o, Object arg)`, the second parameter will be the string `"season"`.

Or declared an `enum MyAttr {Season, DayInTime, Temperature}` and call `notifyObservers(MyAttr.Season);`

Answer (score 0):

If `season`, `dayInTime` and `temperature` should be send to observer at the same time, it may be better to call:

```
notifyObservers(season, dayInTime, temperature)
```

and `Observer` can have a method `update(Object season, Object dayInTime, Object temperature)`, now you know whether it's season, dayInTime, or temperature.